# Ghostscript converting Postscript to PNG is over-saturated

Tags: png, imagemagick, postscript, ghostscript

I'm trying to use Ghostscript and/or ImageMagick to convert each page of a Postscript document into PNG images. The problem is that both produce images that are way too saturated (I think that's the right terminology).

Here are the commands I'm trying:

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=png16m -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -sOutputFile=page_%02d.png brochure.ps
convert brochure.ps im_page_%02d.png
```

[This is the input Postscript file](http://www.filedropper.com/brochure_1) (brochure.ps from above)

Here's a couple of the output images I'm getting:

[Page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ml21n.png)

[Page 6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OgCZU.png)

As you can see (especially on the page with the big green map of New Hampshire), the colors of the output PNGs are too bright/saturated. How can I prevent the colors from being changed so much and get a more accurate conversion?

Preview in OS X 10.6 automatically does [a very accurate conversion](https://imgur.com/TeVt1.jpg) to PNG when you open a Postscript file in it. This leads me to believe there is just something screwy with the way ghostscript converts ps->png (I'm fairly confident ImageMagick is just a wrapper for ghostscript for this operation). Is there a tool besides ghostscript I should be using instead?

Note: As pipitas points out below, the visible difference of colors varies by OS. It is very obvious in OS X 10.6, but apparently not very noticeable in Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right in assuming ImageMagick just being a wrapper for Ghostscript when converting from PostScript or PDF to an image format.

I think, this problem can only be solved to anybody's satisfaction once the efforts to add support for ICC profile handling and color management (currently underway) are [completed for Ghostscript (design document as PDF)](http://svn.ghostscript.com/ghostscript/trunk/gs/doc/GS9_Color_Management.pdf). That point in time is close, however. If I understand recent commits to http://svn.ghostscript.com/trunk/ correctly, the next release (which will be dubbed 9.00 and out hopefully in August) will include support for color management via [LittleCMS](http://www.littlecms.com/). Yay!

Comment: BTW, I looked at your **brochure.ps** (using `gswin32.exe` on WinXP) as well as at your **page1.png** and **page6.png** (using the Chrome browser). On ***my*** notebook, there is hardly any visible difference in their color saturation. This result does ***not*** make the need for Ghostscript color management support superfluous, but rather re-enforces it.

Answer (score 0):

OSX 10.4 and up provide sips (scriptable image processing system) and it works well with PDF format. Perhaps it can be a temporary solution until Ghostscript supports color management.